# How to solve an equation in three variables fixing two of the variables?

Tags: polynomials, roots, computer-algebra-systems

Also, I have the following equation, I want to solve it for $b$ keeping $a$ and $c$ fixed.

$5b^5+(60-5a)b^4+(125+50c-80a)b^3+(594c-445a-775)b^2+(2324c-1005a-3270)b+3000c-750a-3000=0.$

Also how to solve it in Maple?

Comment: I think this one may be help to you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function wiki says how to solve fifth order equation.think entire coefficient of b as constant and use wiki article to solve the equation

Comment: Sometimes, a numerical solution maybe the best we can get from an equation. I doubt you will get much out of Maple without switching to numerical method.